# Will the `hooks.invalid` be called when sth invalid?

Tags: javascript, webpack, frontend

## docs description

the docs of webpack
said `hooks.invalid` will be `Executed when a watching compilation has been invalidated.`

> https://webpack.js.org/api/compiler-hooks/#invalid

But the source code is a little confused

## source code

### where the invalid to be called

``

```
    watch(files, dirs, missing) {
    this.pausedWatcher = null;
    this.watcher = this.compiler.watchFileSystem.watch(
        files,
        dirs,
        missing,
        this.startTime,
        this.watchOptions,
        (
            err,
            fileTimeInfoEntries,
            contextTimeInfoEntries,
            changedFiles,
            removedFiles
        ) => {
            this.pausedWatcher = this.watcher;
            this.watcher = null;
            if (err) {
                this.compiler.modifiedFiles = undefined;
                this.compiler.removedFiles = undefined;
                this.compiler.fileTimestamps = undefined;
                this.compiler.contextTimestamps = undefined;
                return this.handler(err);
            }
            this.compiler.fileTimestamps = fileTimeInfoEntries;
            this.compiler.contextTimestamps = contextTimeInfoEntries;
            this.compiler.removedFiles = removedFiles;
            this.compiler.modifiedFiles = changedFiles;
            if (!this.suspended) {
                this._invalidate();
            }
        },
        (fileName, changeTime) => {
            this.compiler.hooks.invalid.call(fileName, changeTime);
        }
    );
}
```

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/fd056e27f477e364c16d1b09b39905fce28c13ca/lib/Watching.js#L252

### where the `watchFileSystem.watch` 's 7th argument used

```
watch(files, dirs, missing, startTime, options, callback, callbackUndelayed) {
    if (!Array.isArray(files)) {
        throw new Error("Invalid arguments: 'files'");
    }
    if (!Array.isArray(dirs)) {
        throw new Error("Invalid arguments: 'dirs'");
    }
    if (!Array.isArray(missing)) {
        throw new Error("Invalid arguments: 'missing'");
    }
    if (typeof callback !== "function") {
        throw new Error("Invalid arguments: 'callback'");
    }
    if (typeof startTime !== "number" && startTime) {
        throw new Error("Invalid arguments: 'startTime'");
    }
    if (typeof options !== "object") {
        throw new Error("Invalid arguments: 'options'");
    }
    if (typeof callbackUndelayed !== "function" && callbackUndelayed) {
        throw new Error("Invalid arguments: 'callbackUndelayed'");
    }
    const oldWatcher = this.watcher;
    this.watcher = new Watchpack(options);

    if (callbackUndelayed) {
        this.watcher.once("change", callbackUndelayed);
    }
  // some other things
 }
```

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/2a9452e51b38b86503ba30a76c65f906b3f99728/lib/node/NodeWatchFileSystem.js#L45

Would anyone make me clear？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the source code. You probably just saw wrongly. I have added comments after each argument.

The watcher object extends the EventEmitter object, and the `callbackUndelayed` callback was registered to the change event listener. Finally, `this.compiler.hooks.invalid.call(fileName, changeTime)` is invoked when the callback func is invoked when change event is emitted.

```
this.watcher = this.compiler.watchFileSystem.watch(
    files, // 1st arg
    dirs, // 2nd arg
    missing, // 3rd arg
    this.startTime, // 4th arg
    this.watchOptions, // 5th arg
    (
            err,
            fileTimeInfoEntries,
            contextTimeInfoEntries,
            changedFiles,
            removedFiles
    ) => {
            this.pausedWatcher = this.watcher;
            this.watcher = null;
            if (err) {
                    this.compiler.modifiedFiles = undefined;
                    this.compiler.removedFiles = undefined;
                    this.compiler.fileTimestamps = undefined;
                    this.compiler.contextTimestamps = undefined;
                    return this.handler(err);
            }
            this.compiler.fileTimestamps = fileTimeInfoEntries;
            this.compiler.contextTimestamps = contextTimeInfoEntries;
            this.compiler.removedFiles = removedFiles;
            this.compiler.modifiedFiles = changedFiles;
            if (!this.suspended) {
                    this._invalidate();
            }
    }, // 6th arg
    (fileName, changeTime) => {
            this.compiler.hooks.invalid.call(fileName, changeTime);
    } // 7th arg (the one you're looking at)
```

Comment: So  `this.watcher.once('change')` would leads to  the invalidation of the compilation

Comment: yes, the `watcher` object extends the `EventEmitter` object, and the `callbackUndelayed` callback was registered to the `change` event listener. Finally, `this.compiler.hooks.invalid.call(fileName, changeTime)` is invoked when the callback  func is invoked when `change` event is emitted.